# DateTime() is not working

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache, PHP, MySQL separately (without WampServer).
Now I would like to run following code

```
<?php
$d1=new DateTime('NOW');
print_r( $d1 ) ;
?>
```

But I am not getting any output.
When I run same code on WampServer I got expected result.
Do I require to make any changes in settings?

Comment: `$d1 = new DateTime();` timestamp not needed for "now".

Comment: DateTime is only available for php v >=  5.2.0

Comment: DateTime is available since PHP 5.2.0. Turn on your error logging to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1409082)

Comment: why not $d1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  or any format you want?

Comment: using PHP Version 5.3.25.. still not working

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: set error reporting to: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Do you get anything at all? What do you get when you `echo "Hello World!";`?

Comment: [Should work as expected](http://3v4l.org/hl9l1)

Comment: `$d1 = new DateTime(); echo $d1->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 2):

If this is Your fresh install of PHP You need to set:

`date.timezone = Europe/Warsaw`

in Your php.ini config file.

The list of all timezones can be found here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: What's f.ex? Please don't use non-obvious shorthands in your answers

Answer (score 1):

you have to edit your `php.ini` file in folder `wampp/php` and set the `date.timezone` to you timezone and try a format like

`$d1 = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");`